# Some bugs in a dynamic form that I would LOVE to get fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, dynamic-forms

I've went all out on the Fiddle here so that you get (most of) the picture:

http://jsfiddle.net/ch29z/11/

When you click + in the first row, it clones the + in its highlighted state, so the copy is green.

If you set the first row to eg. agent = excel, when it clones, the first dropdown is set back to tags, but the 2nd and 3rd remain as "=" and "excel"

If you add a 2nd row, but then delete the first row, then add another row, the spacing between the items differs from when you're first adding the rows (IMO the spacing is actually better once you've done that, it's a CSS issue obviously but I just can't get it to sit right.)

Also, when you select variant, then bad, then go back to variant, the text box is duplicated so that there are now 2, if you repeat the process ANOTHER text box is added.

Not sure why this is happening as the code is the same for all other dynamically generated textboxes.

Any help regarding these bugs is greatly appreciated, another few pairs of eyes really do help.

Regards,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(this).parent().find(".valuestextbox").remove();
```

Seemed to do the trick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The space seems to come from the margin you set on your select:

```
.dropdownclone select {
...
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

For the`div.autocomplete` you should have it ready in the DOM and play with a `style="display:none"`, like you do with the `select`. But if you like to inject it like you do, you need to check if it does not exist already.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any ideas how to implement the check? I have tried the following: `var variantClones = $('.valuestextbox').size() + $('.valuestextboxclone').size();
    
    if (variantClones < 1) {
        $values.after($valuestextbox.clone());
    }
    
    if (variantClones >= 1) {
        return;
    }` but if you change between two options that produce a text box, then the automcomplete list does not update, it remains the same list as it was for the first text box. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: May be each time you make `$values.after($valuestextbox.clone())` do a `$values.find('div.autocomplete').remove()` before. But man, this is a strange code, with plenty of repetitions you are trying to run here.

Comment: thanks for your help - this seemed to do the trick in the spot you mentioned: `$(this).parent().find(".valuestextbox").remove();`